# Why must any solution of this congruence equation satisfy gcd(x,11)=1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Solve the congruence $x^5\equiv 3 \space mod \space 11$

The solution says that any solution of this equation must satisfy gcd(x,11)=1 and I'm not sure why.

I understand the theorem : "the linear diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ has solutions iff $gcd(a,b)|c$" but in this case the congruence is not linear...

Is it perhaps to do with the fact that if $gcd(x,11) >1$ then the gcd would have to be 11 and that would mean that x is divisible by 11 and thus $x \equiv 0\space mod \space 11$ and thus we would have $(0)^5 \equiv 3 \space mod \space 11$ and in this case we would of course not have any solution?

Comment: Completely correct.

Comment: The afirmation is true

Answer (score 2):

As you said, if $\gcd(x, 11)>1$ then it is $11$ and if $11|x$ it is easy to see that $x^5$ is congruent with $0$ $\mod {11}$